# php function not returning class object

Tags: php, oop, class, object

I have a DB class that I've created several functions in to return various values.  One of the functions returns (or is supposed to) a "user" class object that represents a logged in user for the application.

```
class user {
   public $guid = '';
   public $fname = '';
   public $lname = '';

   public function __construct() {}

   public function print_option() {
         return "<option value='$this->guid'>$this->name</option>";
   }
}
```

In the DB class I have the following 2 functions:

```
public function get_user($uid) {
    $sql = '';
    $usr = new user();
    $sql = "SELECT guid, fname, lname FROM ms.users WHERE guid=?";

    if($sth = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $sth->bind_param('s', $uid);
        if($sth->execute()) {
            $sth->bind_result($usr->guid, $usr->fname, $usr->lname);
            $sth->fetch();
            print_r($usr);  // PRINTS OUT CORRECTLY
            return $usr;
        }
        else {return null;}
    }
    else {return null;}
}

public function get_practice_user_list($pguid) {
    $ret = '';
    $sql = "SELECT user_guid FROM ms.perm WHERE p_guid=?";
    if($sth = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $sth->bind_param('s', $pguid);
        if($sth->execute()) {
            $usr = new user();
            $guid = '';

            $sth->bind_result($guid);
            while($sth->fetch()) {
                print_r($guid);  // PRINTS GUID correctly
                $usr = $this->get_user($guid);
                print_r($usr);   // PRINTS NOTHING object is null so prints "error" two lines later.
                if($usr != null) $ret .= $usr->print_option();
                else print "error";
            }

            return $ret;
        }
        else {return null;}
    }
    else {return null;}
}
```

I'm just not understanding why the "user" object is not returning in this instance.  Others calls to the get_user function work just fine and return the user class object pertaining to that user.

TIA

Comment: Which function are you calling and what exactly is it returning?

Comment: I'm starting with the get_practice_user_list function.  Right now it returns nothing

Comment: It must return something, even if that something is `null`.

Comment: @LukeMills, yes it is returning `null`.  Like I said when it's returning from the `get_user` function the if block says that it's null so it prints "error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the query.  Since the code was just looping through one query (`get_practice_user_list`), then calling the `get_user` function and attempting a second query MySQL came back with an error of `out of sync` message.  When I looked that up, I was able to fix it by doing a `fetch_all` on the first query then looping through that array to get the users.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you guid may be an integer so

```
    $sth->bind_param('s', $uid);
```

bind_param's first param should be 'i' not 's';

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Like I said it populates inside the `get_user` functions, but then the return doesn't show in `get_practice_user_list`